# Programmatically give password to Symfony code

Tags: python, laravel, symfony

I already login as an administrator but in php coding I enter the code, below. I am confused about how to write this query `ShellCommandline()` with `sudo` or not. Both conditions give me a different error.

```
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('python /home/machine/openface/demos/compare_two_pic.py {/home/machine/openface/demos/images/5G5X0dnI5xkD.jpg, /home/machine/openface/demos/images/orange.jpg}');

$process->run();

echo "here".$process->getOutput();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Is `sudo` needed before the python command? If yes, then how do I programmatically provide the password?

Output
[image]

Comment: isn't tthat you dont need any sudo ? just give permission to the server user ( www , apache , httpd ... ) to run the file ? or you have in py script some code who needs to be run as root ?

Comment: I have python code i give full access to www folder through command line

Comment: so what is the error at the end ? i didnt understand , sorry

Comment: After execute this code. I got import dlib error which is installed in system. Please see the above image

Comment: im sorry for this question but did you run pip install dlib comment ?

Comment: if your python script works fine in commend line, consider permission to users 775 on all PYTHONPATH directory ( maybe is not the right way to handle permission issues ) but, run chmod 755 on all directories in python path. if you are sure that the commend was executed by sudo commend, try to add python path to /etc/sudoers